# Newbie in C - wrong return type

Tags: c

I have a function similar to this using pointers in C

```
float *compute_avg(float *array, int num_elements) {
  float sum = 0.f;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

But error occurs "return value type does not match function type".

Comment: Your return type is `float *` but you're trying to return a `float` - you probably just want to fix the return type (remove the `*`).

Comment: OP: please don't rollback constructive edits - see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your function returns a `float *`, and you're trying to return a `float`. You can just remove the `*` to change the first line to `float compute_avg(float *array, int num_elements)`

You can also declare sum as a float * and then malloc memory for it. Then you should use `*sum += array[i];`, but remember to `free` it later.

Comment: Using dynamic allocation for the sum variable here makes no sense whatsoever. And you'd need to free it at some point.

Comment: Obviously changing the return type of the function is a better solution, but using a pointer to sum is still a solution, and i see no reason to don't use it. Since the author of the question is clearly learning about pointers, it's useful for him to know alternatives. Also, since you mentioned it, I'll edit the answer to add a reminder of freeing sum, so it'll be even more useful for a learner.